# getting choice values from django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have this model:

```
class ShipClass (models.Model):
    ALLEGIENCE_CHOICES = (
    ('FED', 'Federation'),
    ('KGE', 'Klingon Empire'),
    ('RSE', 'Romulan Star Empire')
    )
    Origin = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ALLEGIENCE_CHOICES, default='FED')
    ClassName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    NumberOfCrew = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ClassName

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("Origin", "ClassName")
```

right now, I have this in the view:

```
def shipclasses(request):
    qs = models.ShipClass.objects.order_by("Origin", "NumberOfCrew")
    return render_to_response('fleet/templates/Ship_Classes.html', {'qs' : qs})
```

Origin is the three-letter code.  Is there a way that I can get the full text of the "origin" field from the ALLEGIENCE_CHOICES in the view instead so I can show that on the template?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def shipclasses(request):
    qs = models.ShipClass.objects.order_by("Origin", "NumberOfCrew")        
    return render_to_response('fleet/templates/Ship_Classes.html', {'qs' : qs})
```

no need to change your views. just do it in template:

```
{% for q in qs %}
  {{ q.get_origin_diplay }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Very cool. Django is am awesome language. Thank you very much.

Comment: @arcee123 my pleasure. indeed, python and its django is the most awesome thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's what for `Model.get_FOO_display()`

```
querySearch = ShipClass.objects.order_by("Origin", "NumberOfCrew")
querySearch.get_origin_display()
```

Now you will get 'Federation' ...